# Image quality is very low after capture with camera in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-camera, android-camera2, android-image-capture

I am making this `camera` app where I take the `picture` and `upload` to server. But after captured image that I am getting `very` **`low` `quality`**. Can we specify the image `quality` here?

```
val cameraLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview()
    ) { bitmap  ->
        val file = ImageConverter.bitmapToFile(context,bitmap)
        onResultCamera(bitmap, file)
    }
```

To launch camera

```
cameraLauncher.launch()
```

Comment: It is called `TakePicturePreview` for a reason - you won't ever get a high quality image using that contract. Have you considered using `TakePicture`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake TakePicture wont return the bitmap

Comment: Do you want a low quality thumbnail sized bitmap or do you want a high quality image? You have to pick, you can't get both.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I want high quality image.

Comment: Then switch to using `TakePicture` instead of `TakePicturePreview`, as Ian suggests.